# How do I get notification of the battery power level from the Windows kernel?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, power-management

I need to write code in C that will indicate and notify me when the laptop battery power is low.  I know that I can use the following:

```
BOOL WINAPI GetSystemPowerStatus(
    __out  LPSYSTEM_POWER_STATUS lpSystemPowerStatus
    );
```

But I want to send a function to the operating system that will notify me when power is low.

I want to have an "empty" loop in my code, and when battery is low, the code will send me a notification (`printf` or `trace`).

I think I should be using kernel functions, but I can't find them

Comment: Since when does Windows allow kernel programming?

Comment: @Shahbaz On Windows, "kernel programming" is basically "writing a driver". But what's probably confusing you is [the difference between the kernel and kernel mode](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/04/17/10294294.aspx). Windows does export "kernel" functions that have nothing to do with running in kernel mode.

Comment: Where have you gotten the idea that this needs to involve kernel *anything*? What's wrong with calling `GetSystemPowerStatus`? Do you mean that you effectively want the operating system to *call back* your code when the power level hits certain pre-defined points?

Comment: yes - exactly.. I'm sorry for the confusing words, I'm kinda new in this still

Comment: It's quite common belief that the kernel consists of super-cool and omnipotent methods. And the only purpose of the "kernel" itself is to keep those methods out of mortals reach.

Comment: @user1386966 Whats wrong in using `WM_TIMER` to call `GetSystemPowerStatus` at regular intervals?

Comment: @Agent Constant polling is hardly ever the correct way to solve a problem. It would "work", for loose definitions of the term "work". But I wouldn't design an app around it.

Comment: @CodyGray indeed, especially monitoring battery by draining it is counter-productive. But rarely outside world variables have OnThresholdReached hooks.

Comment: I don;t want to use timers, Callback function is better i think - but the API that @Cody Gray suggested is working with desktop apps only -and I need it to be able to work with the driver as well

Comment: @user1386966 Driver?? What driver?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have never used these APIs, but what you are looking for seems to be [`WM_POWERBROADCAST`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373247.aspx).

There are various values for `wParam` that you could check upon receiving that message, such as `PBT_APMBATTERYLOW`. When you receive a `WM_POWERBROADCAST` message with the appropriate `wParam` value, call [`GetSystemPowerStatus()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372693.aspx) from there.

Comment: thank you, but the problem that this API is working with desktop apps only.

Comment: @user1386966 Yes? Where in your question do you mention anything else? Do you have some silent, secret requirement that you aren't telling us about?

Answer (score 1):

In the kernel, there is a separate methodology for handling power status updates.  See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff565766%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for info.

> If you are writing a driver that can be affected by power-state
>   changes, you must be able to process the following types of
>   information in your driver code:

etc.